# Tooltip text alignment in Highcharts for 'direction: rtl'

Tags: css, highcharts, arabic, hebrew

When I set `direction: rtl;` to the `body` I get this bug in Highcharts:

[image]

When `direction` is `ltr` then it is ok:

[image]

I made all the changes related to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/buYCZ/ from documentation, and the only problem is that text is not aligned properly in tooltip.

Also I tried to resolve it with css hacks, but it isn't working at all. Or I am supposed to write a custom formatter function for that?

**//UPDATED:** Fiddle with the error: http://jsfiddle.net/7cHth/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/buYCZ/98/ seems to working fine, so please updaete my code with yours to replicate this issue.

Comment: Forked the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cHth/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set `useHTML` as true for the toolitp,  in your chart

http://jsfiddle.net/7cHth/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used it but when compile highchart in website you should include HTML.